# XML Schema .xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I cant seem to figure out how to make an xsd for this xml file, could anyone help me write the schema for this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<raml version="2.0" xmlns="example.xsd">
  <cmData type="example">
    <header>
      <log dateTime="2017-11-03T08:18:01" action="created" 
       appInfo="exportr">UIValues are used</log>
  </header>
<managedObject class="aaaa" version="a" distName="name" id="1">
  <p name="link">example</p>
  <p name="name">xyz</p>
  <p name="other">abcd</p>
</managedObject>
<managedObject class="bbbb" version="a" distName="name1" id="2">
  <p name="auto">AB123</p>
  <p name="name">wrg</p>
  <p name="Other1">abcdef</p>
  <p name="height">11111</p>
  <p name="other">1234456</p>
  <p name="length">123454"</p>
  <p name="other2">65984984"</p>
</managedObject>
</cmData>
```

Comment: [**Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

For any given XML document, there's an infinite number of schemas against which it is valid. To define the "correct" schema, you need to know what class of documents you want to define, and that can't be done by providing a single instance. For example, we could look at your instance document and notice that paragraphs with `@name="name"` always have a value consisting of three lower-case ASCII letters: but we have no idea whether or not that is a general property of the whole class of documents.

I suspect (though it's a wild guess) that you want to define some kind of rules that say "if the name of a paragraph is X then the content must be of type T". You cannot define that kind of rule in XSD 1.0, but you can do so in XSD 1.1, using a feature called "type alternatives".